# Why does my Nginx alias redirect not work (Goes to 404)?

Tags: redirect, nginx, alias

I have my main site at x.com (@ **/var/www/x.com/index.html**)

```
# MAIN LOCATION
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #autoindex on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I want **/v2** to redirect to another local dir (@ **/var/www/x.com/v2/public/index.html**)

```
# Redirect beta site
location /v2 {
        alias    /var/www/x.com/v2/public;
}
```

This seems like it should work, but instead, it's going to my 404 site. Not sure if this matters, but here is my root above both of them:

```
# path
root    /var/www/throneoflies.com/html;
```

I tried ordering **"/v2"** both above **"/"** and below - didn't seem to make a difference. I read I shouldn't use 'root' instead of 'alias' because it's a different schema (/v2/public/ and not just /v2/).

**EDIT:** Seems like it should be working - I've read a lot since this post. Here is my full file:

```
server {
        # MAIN >>
        # SSL configuration
        listen                  443 default_server ssl;
        server_name             www.x.com;
        error_page 404          /error/404.html;
        server_tokens           off;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/x.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/x.com/key.pem;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        #ssl_session_tickets    off;
        ssl_ciphers             EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # path
        root                    /var/www/x.com/html;
        #root                   /var/www/x.com/v2/public; #works!

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        index                   index.html;

        # 404 handling - no cache
        location = /404.html {
                add_header      Cache-Control "no-cache" always;
        }

        # Redirect beta site : Why doesn't it work if the outer block root changed to the same path works? I can REPLACE my "/" with this v2 path np. However, alias at /v2 does not work.
        location = /v2 {
                alias           /var/www/x.com/v2/public;
                #root           /var/www/x.com/v2/public;
                #try_files      $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # MAIN LOCATION
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
                #autoindex      on;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # DENY .HTACCESS ACCESS
        location ~/\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: The `location /v2` block seems fine. Does `/v2` redirect to `/v2/` before the 404 response? Is there an `index` directive in the outer block?

Comment: I don't see a visible redirect, if that's what you mean. Index directive? Yea just `index index.html;`

Comment: (It's a CAUGHT 404, not the ugly nginx 404 from outer `error_page 404          /error/404.html;`). Also, if I swap the main root with the alias I'm trying to do, the /v2/public/ site loads FINE! So it's not a path issue

Comment: @RichardSmith I added my full file above

Comment: Your EDIT shows `location = /v2` which is not the same as your original question (and will definitely not work)

Comment: OH! Thanks, Richard. That was definitely 1 issue. See any others? I was hoping that was it.

Answer (score 1):

This should obviously be caused by the `=` in your `location = /v2`, which will only match requests where the `$uri` is exactly `/v2`; the correct way would most likely be to remove `=`.

Additionally, note that if using `location /v2 {alias /var/www/x.com/v2/public;}`, then folks would also be able to access things like `/var/www/x.com/v2/public.bak` through `/v2.bak`; if that's not intentional, then you would be better off having trailing slashes, as appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, this first line was already suggested by Richard Oct 4th - since the suggestion, I tried it and edited (+commented below Richard): It seemed to be 1 of the issues, but the issue is still not resolved. 

Looking into your 2nd suggestion now. Interesting, I didn't think trailing slashes were important! Does the root not having a trailing slash mean anything? Or the root doesn't matter at all since we're doing alias?

Comment: As an update, I tried trailing slash and same. Curious, I made an alias to the exact same location as my main site that works -- and that doesn't work, either! Something seems seriously wrong with alias. Perhaps something outside of this block? Another clue is that if I set the outside block root to the /v2/public/ it WORKS -- if I put the root inside, it doesn't work. No aliases seem to work, and root doesn't seem to update if I put it again on an inside block.

Comment: @DylanHunt can you show how you are testing this? curl -v will be really helpful also, if you could please paste some error.log lines